# Line breaks not pasting into multi-line text box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having an issue preserving line breaks when copying text from one multi-line text area to another, then emailing said text.

The line breaks look fine until the Outlook email is opened. When right-clicking and 'viewing source' on the email, the text is formatted correctly.

Relevant code:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Dim linebreak = vbCrLf
sb.Append("some data"& linebreak & linebreak)
sb.Append("more data" & linebreak & linebreak)
txtData.Text = sb.ToString()

'Textbox html
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustInfo" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="265px"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is the textbox I am pasting the above into:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
```

This then gets sent in an Outlook email

```
Public Sub SendRequest(ByVal message As String, Optional ByVal SendToEmailAddress As String = "", Optional ByVal AddToSubjectLine As String = "", Optional ByVal attachment As String = "")

    Dim msg As New EmailMessage
    msg.Body = message

    'Send message

End Sub
```

Anyone experience this before? Thanks.

Comment: How about trying Environment.NewLine() instead.  Not sure if VB has that or not.

Comment: I have tried this, I have also added wrap="false" to the textbox that is receiving the text. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you have to define linebreak as a string....... "Dim linebreak = vbCrLf" should be "Dim linebreak as string = vbCrLf"

Comment: This did not work, but thank you the reply

Comment: What browser?  It works fine for me in Firefox, Chrome and (old) IE.  In your code you have 3 different text box IDs - there isn't some confusion?  Actually I'm a little confused about exactly where and when it isn't displaying correctly, and the relationship between all the different text boxes.

Comment: @AdamHeeg, `Environment.NewLine` is .NET... it isn't language specific

Comment: reading this might answer your question since you are using Outlook: http://forums.asp.net/t/1220479.aspx?Email+text+message+line+breaks+not+working

Comment: any reason why you wouldn't use `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` over `EmailMessage`?

Comment: EmailMessage is a custom class we have developed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
Public Sub SendRequest(ByVal message As String, Optional ByVal SendToEmailAddress As String = "", Optional ByVal AddToSubjectLine As String = "", Optional ByVal attachment As String = "")

    Dim msg As New EmailMessage
    msg.Body = message
    msg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html; 'set the MailFormat
    'Send message

End Sub
```

Let me know if this works for you. I've experienced similar things with Outlook but using `MailMessage`.

Comment: I think it's more likely that setting the format to Text would work.  HTML will ignore the line breaks - all white space is treated equally by HTML

Comment: I'll leave as is until OP responds

Comment: I've just found that vbcrlf does not render when body format is set to html, it does when set to text. Though, maybe not the right answer, it led me to it. Thank you